# How do I compile and run pyqtdeploy's pre-packaged demo application?

Tags: python, android, pyqt5

Compiling openssl from a sysroot fails to find stdlib (when running pyqtdeploy's demo for PyQT5 on android)

How to I make sure the standard library can be found?

In trying to make a python android app using PyQT, [pyqtdeploy](https://pypi.org/project/pyqtdeploy/#files) seems to be the official tool that supports Python3 & PyQT5 (buildozer doesn't seem to)

However, it has limited documentation. There is  a demo supplied, but is missing APK build steps. I got so far as to get it to start compilation, but I get an error finding the standard library, even though I have `build-essentials` and `libc6-dev` installed.

I [unzip the latest pyqtdeploy demo](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/51/b03310c5553da1da1e437387ccd044a7242e4d3b3d1d54ec4dc066e1d6e3/pyqtdeploy-2.1.tar.gz) from [the source code download site](https://pypi.org/project/pyqtdeploy/#files) and download some extra dependancies:

```
cd pyqtdeploy-2.1/demo
cd src
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.6/Python-3.6.6.tar.xz
wget http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/qt/archive/qt/5.11/5.11.1/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1.tar.xz
wget http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/qt/archive/qt/5.11/5.11.1/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1.tar.xz
wget https://superb-sea2.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pyqt/sip/sip-4.19.12/sip-4.19.12.tar.gz
cd -
```

And then I run

```
ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 ANDROID_NDK_PLATFORM=android-28 ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=~/Android/android-ndk-r17b python3  build-demo.py --target android-32
```

It compiles for a bit then fails:

---

```
generating dummy tests (if needed)...
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jonny/Projects/organic-mail/tools/pyqtdeploy-2.1/demo/sysroot-android-32/build/openssl-1.0.2p/test'
ideatest.c => dummytest.c
md2test.c => dummytest.c
rc5test.c => dummytest.c
mdc2test.c => dummytest.c
jpaketest.c => dummytest.c
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jonny/Projects/organic-mail/tools/pyqtdeploy-2.1/demo/sysroot-android-32/build/openssl-1.0.2p/test'

Configured for android.

*** Because of configuration changes, you MUST do the following before
*** building:

    make depend
making depend in crypto...
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jonny/Projects/organic-mail/tools/pyqtdeploy-2.1/demo/sysroot-android-32/build/openssl-1.0.2p/crypto'
In file included from cryptlib.c:117:0:
cryptlib.h:62:21: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 # include <stdlib.h>
```

Aha, this may be related: the `sysroot-android-32/include` directory is empty.
The pyqtdeploy-sysroot tool is supposed to make a sysroot for each target platform

When I ignore building openssl, I get an error for SIP: `'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libsip.a': No such file`

Comment: Feel free to move this to stackoverflow if it is too programmery

Comment: It appears it is possible, but it may be version dependant: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2016-April/037380.html

Comment: I have been able to build the pyqt-demo application for android and wrote a small guide : https://medium.com/@Lola_Dam/packaging-pyqt-application-using-pyqtdeploy-for-both-linux-and-android-32ac7824708b

It is not a proper answer to your question but hope that can help people who also had a hard time having this working.